# How to show convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log \left(\frac{n^{2}+a^{2}}{n^{2}}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How do I show this series converges?

---

consider the function $$F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{n^{2}+x^{2}}$$

for $a>0$ it has been shown: $$\int_{0}^{a} F(x) d x=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log \left(\frac{n^{2}+a^{2}}{n^{2}}\right)$$

**a) Show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log \left(\frac{n^{2}+a^{2}}{n^{2}}\right)$ is convergent $\forall a\in \mathbb{R}$**

How do I go on with this problem? I think I should exploit somehow that it's related to the antiderivative of $F(x)$.
Else I tried the ratio test, comparison criteria, integral test. But I can't find a solution. And I don't know if they want me to examine both uniform and pointwise convergence.

Comment: $\log\left(\frac{n^2+a^2}{n^2}\right) \sim \frac{a^2}{n^2}$ as $n\to +\infty$.

Comment: @Rigel is $log((n^2+a^2)/n^2))\leq a^2/n^2$ $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\forall a\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Yes, it is. In general $0\leq \log(1+t)\leq t$ for every $t\geq 0$ (and this is enough, in your case, to prove convergence), and $\log(1+t)\sim t$ for $t\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

We can do better: using the product representation of the Gamma function, one could ultimately show
$$
\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{a^2}{n^2}\right) = \frac{\sinh(\pi a)}{\pi a}
$$Exercise: how does this relate to your sum?